# tmux: C-PageUp and C-PageDown seem not to work

Tags: vim, tmux

The default VIM key sequence to navigate to the previous/next tab is C-PageUp and C-PageDown, respectively.  It appears that these sequences do not work under either tmux 1.5 or 1.6, and I've tried under Centos as well as Ubuntu.  I tried unbinding the sequence in my .tmux.conf, but that had no effect.

Easy enough to recreate:

1. Start a tmux session
2. vim xxx.dat
3. :tabnew yyy.dat
4. Try to alternate tabs with C-PageUp/C-PageDown. Nada.

Repeat steps 2-4 outside of tmux and the tab switching works as it should.

Comment: `gt` and `gT` are faster.

Comment: I've extensively edited the question, which I believe is actually valid. I've looked for a solution myself, but none of the ones suggested (rebinding keys) seem to work. I suggest that the question is re-open, possibly on other sites such as Vi&Vim or SuperUser.